# Is there a minimum PHP upload_max_size limit

Tags: php, upload-max-filesize

I am working with another agency on a website where they control the server. I have asked them to lower the PHP `upload_max_filesize` value to 6MB as there is no need for a larger value, but they have told me that their setup cannot go below 20MB. The `post_max_size` is set to 8MB. I have reviewed the php.net docs and there is nothing mentioned about minimum limits.

Could someone tell me if this is nonsense or are there unique setups that are configured to have minimum limits?

Comment: You probably are on a shared environment and the configuration is for all users, not just yours.

Comment: I'm with @JayBlanchard - it is nonsense. Maybe you could use an entry in php.ini in your own folders. Failing in that, maybe an ini_set() in your own code?

Comment: @Yishmeray Would a restrictive shared hosting environment prevent having individual PHP settings for each domain?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the case, though I have not encountered it myself.